# How to jam the axis of a pgfplots plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I need to have some kind of jump on the axis of the plot in `pgfplots` package. Something similar to the following figure where some part of the scales are jammed.

[image]

It would be interesting to have even different scales for the top and botoom traces (exactly like the figure).

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can simply use two axes that you position relative to each other.

Here's an example where I've defined a new key `axis break gap` that can be used to set the gap between the axes:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\tikzset{
    axis break gap/.initial=1mm
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            name=bottom axis,
            domain = 0:pi,
            scale only axis,
            width=8cm, height=4cm,
            axis x line*=bottom
        ]
            \addplot [smooth] {-cos(deg(x))^6/10+0.2};
            \addplot [smooth] {-cos(deg(x))^6/10+0.4};
        \end{axis}
        \begin{axis}[
            at=(bottom axis.north),
            anchor=south, yshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/axis break gap},
            domain = 0:pi,
            scale only axis,
            width=8cm, height=4cm,
            axis x line*=top,
            xticklabel=\empty,
            after end axis/.code={
                \draw (rel axis cs:0,0) +(-2mm,-1mm) -- +(2mm,1mm)
                    ++(0pt,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/axis break gap})
                    +(-2mm,-1mm) -- +(2mm,1mm)
                    (rel axis cs:1,0) +(-2mm,-1mm) -- +(2mm,1mm)
                    ++(0pt,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/axis break gap})
                    +(-2mm,-1mm) -- +(2mm,1mm);
            }
        ]
            \addplot [smooth] {-cos(deg(x))^6+2};
            \addplot [smooth] {-cos(deg(x))^6+4};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```