# How to draw bar charts with scale breaks?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, bar-chart

I am trying to plot a bar chart with pgfplots. However, I would like to show the outliers with scale breaks in excel, similarly like this (retrieved from [here](https://tomhopper.me/2010/08/30/graphing-highly-skewed-data/)):

[image: example]

The code that I end up with while trying to achieve this, currently is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
range,a
2, 0.028
3, 0.0
4, 0.001
5, 0.0
67, 0.01
68, 0.009
69, 0.012
70, 0.021
71, 0.039
72, 0.054
73, 0.073
74, 0.09
75, 0.133
76, 0.151
77, 0.244
78, 0.27
79, 0.377
80, 0.48
81, 0.508
82, 0.605
83, 0.846
84, 1.012
85, 1.193
86, 1.387
87, 1.54
88, 1.569
89, 1.907
90, 1.933
91, 1.902
92, 1.931
93, 1.748
94, 1.633
95, 1.356
96, 1.145
97, 0.886
98, 0.688
99, 0.432
100, 0.2
101, 0.17
102, 0.09
103, 0.04
104, 0.03
105, 0.0
106, 0.01
107, 0.01
108, 0.01
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}\results

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[]
\centering  
  \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.55]
            \begin{axis} [xlabel={}, 
            ylabel={},
            clip=false,
            axis x line*=bottom,
            ymin=0,
            axis y line*=left,
            xmin=0,
            ymax=10,
            legend pos=north east,
            ybar =0,
            xtick distance={20},
            bar width=1,
            xtick distance={20},
            ytick distance={2},
            restrict x to domain*=0:140,
            restrict y to domain*=0:10,
            extra y ticks={10},
            extra y tick style={grid=major},
            ]

            \addplot+[orange] table[x=range, y=a, col sep=comma] \results;
            \legend{Data}

            \node [above] at (axis cs: 25,8.9) {\textbf{$=$\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{a}\of\results
                \pgfplotsretval}};

            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}   
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is [answered somewhere by Christian Feuersänger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46651/116936). I think I remember the short answer is : it's not possible out of the box in pgfplots, unless you are a power user and implement it yourself.

Comment: One example of [a solution using PSTricks here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83138/how-to-draw-interrupted-bar-charts-in-pgfplots).

Comment: Well, I have seen this one, but it is done with ps-tricks. I am looking a solution with pgfplots and which can also work with bar width=1.

Comment: Maybe helpful/ related links: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95143/124842 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283460/124842 
 
Not a solution, but an alternative:https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88896/124842